# Azure JavaScript Function App Build fails with "error: Only batch script files are supported for function App - for JavaScript Function App"

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, azure-functions, kudu

I am trying to establish a continuous integration and deployment process for my Azure Function Apps using JavaScript.
I've chosen the **LocalGit** option to deploy. 
However the Kudu Deployment Script is giving me the following error (full log):

> :::::::::::::: log.log :::::::::::::: 
>   2017-11-21T17:22:58.4132910Z,Updating branch
>   '8a7cb2d0d1211305eef99deec082da5501f56e64'.,
>   880855f9-c7b3-47cf-bf3f-773ce1ac0f05,0 
>   2017-11-21T17:22:59.2138570Z,Updating
>   submodules.,72526e2b-9f58-47a1-b493-899e3962b016,0
>   2017-11-21T17:22:59.3622250Z,Preparing deployment for commit id
>   '8a7cb2d0d1'.,582835b0-c3d6-49d1-a3e6-54c5be02bdc8,0
>   2017-11-21T17:23:00.2594900Z,Generating deployment
>   script.,94d00c16-854c-49d1-8be2-36db8a654251,0
>   2017-11-21T17:23:00.5860790Z,Using the following command to generate
>   deployment script: 'azure site deploymentscript -y --no-dot-deployment
>   -r "/home/site/repository" -o "/home/site/deployments/tools" --functionApp --sitePath "/home/site/repository"'.,,0 2017-11-21T17:23:01.7712540Z,Generating deployment script for function
>   App,,0 2017-11-21T17:23:01.7980550Z,error: Only batch script files are
>   supported for function App,,1 2017-11-21T17:23:01.8517310Z,error: Only
>   batch script files are supported for function
>   App\n/opt/Kudu/bin/Scripts/starter.sh
>   "/opt/Kudu/bin/node_modules/.bin/kuduscript" -y --no-dot-deployment -r
>   "/home/site/repository" -o "/home/site/deployments/tools"
>   --functionApp --sitePath "/home/site/repository",,2 2017-11-21T17:23:02.2706970Z,App container will begin restart within
>   10 seconds.,244baa05-fb96-41e5-b570-c2dcd3b9087e,0

What could be the problem? Obviously I don't have any batch script and the Function App could be deployed and is up and running through the Azure Console.

I am using Function App Runtime version: 2.0.1.0 (~1)

Comment: Duplicate of https://github.com/projectkudu/KuduScript/issues/88. Please avoid cross posting without explicit links in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my Function App Runtime was running on Linux. This doesn't seem to support deployment via local Git.
I spun up a Windows Function App Runtime, and now the deployment works.